# LTC2944 shorting

Tags: integrated-circuit, bms, fuel-gauge

So I am using a LTC2944 battery fuel gauge IC. When a 48V(nominal) Li-Ion battery is connected to measure, the IC shorts. When I measure the battery voltage using a multimeter it is 52.6V which is within the 60V the IC can handle.

Cant figure out what is the issue.
Could you also recommend any other battery fuel gauge IC with rating above 60V
[LTC2944 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/2944fa.pdf)[image: MY IC Connection]

Comment: What do you mean by "the ic is shorting"? How do you establish that? What happens when it shorts?

Comment: Which pin(s) short to which pin(s)?

Comment: If I first connect a 12V battery the IC works and I can read the data in the register banks. If I connect the 53V Li-Ion battery I cannot read the data. Then if I reconnect the 12V battery the IC does not work it is permanently damaged.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't fully read the datasheet! There is a section that describes the action of hot-swapping a battery and the necessary voltage clamps that should be in place to protect the sense pins from an overvoltage. Due to the internal (or external) capacitance and the ESL (equivalent series inductance) of the wire(s) or traces, a resonant circuit will form causing an oscillation that will create a voltage much higher than the battery's voltage and exceeding the max voltage of the pin.

A different coulomb counter may be more immune to this problem if its supply voltage is different than the battery's voltage. This particular chip is unique in that sense. But, any circuit where a battery can be hot-swapped has issues if there is no explicit circuitry to gently connect the battery.